# Vee Validate custom required_if rule doesn't computes required

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I am using Vee-validate 2.2.3 on project and trying to use custom required_if rule.
The problem that it doesn't changes required flag on ValidationProvider to true, it always false, so user cannot see that some field became required.
At the same time - validation works well and error messages are shown\hidden when needed.

Examples of code:

```
this.$validator.extend('customRequiredIf', customRequiredIf, {
    hasTarget: true,
    computesRequired: true,
});



const customRequiredIf = (value: any, [target, operation, operationValue] : any) => {
        let conditional = operationValue.length !== 0;
        if (conditional) {
            return {
                valid: value !== undefined && value !== null && value !== "",
                data: {
                    required: value !== undefined && value !== null && value !== "",
                }
            };
        }
        return { 
            valid: true,
            data: {
                required: true
            }
        };
    };
```

What i am doing incorrectly?

Small demo (even though i have always return "required: true", flag "required" - always "false"):
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-4vd30?file=/src/App.vue